# How to I get a spreadsheet button to run a standalone script as me when the sheet is opened by another user account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code in a standalone script that returns the tasks from one of my task lists.

```
var tasklistID="mytaslistid"
function getTasks() {
    var tasks=Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistID)
    return tasks
}
```

The code works fine when called through the installed `onEdit` trigger. But the user may need to simply refresh the list of task on the spreadsheet. So I have inserted a button that calls a function in the bounded script which in turn calls the function in the standalone script

```
function getTasks(){
    TaskManagerScript.getTasks()
}
```

But this only works when the spreadsheet is opened in my account. When opened in another account it returns the other users task.

I tried to flush the spreadsheet and run the `getTasks` function in the `onOpen` trigger but this did not seem to work.

I need assistance to find a workaround.

Comment: Use a web-app to run as "Me" and call this app from your script.

Comment: I think that @TheMaster 's comments can resolve your issue. And I noticed that you are looking for the sample script and flow for resolving your issue. So I proposed a workaround. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: TheMaster response was a bit unclear. I thought he was referring to the deploying both the sheet and script as WebApp. I will try you sample code and get back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your Spreadsheet is shared with users.
- You want to make users run your script by clicking a button on Spreadsheet.
- You want to make users use your task list.

  - The task list is yours.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Reason of your issue:

When users run your script on Spreadsheet by clicking a button on the sheet, the script is run as each user. By this, users cannot find `mytasklistid` of `var tasklistID="mytasklistid"` from user's task list. I think that the reason of your issue is this.

### Workaround:

As one of several workarounds, how about using Web Apps? This is also mentioned by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878612/how-to-i-get-a-spreadsheet-button-to-run-a-standalone-script-as-me-when-the-shee#comment98417802_55878612). When Web Apps is deployed as `Execute the app as: Me`, even if other users run the script of Web Apps, the script is run as owner of Web Apps (you). Under this situation, when users run the script by clicking a button, users request to Web Apps you deployed using UrlFetchApp. By this, users can use your task list ID. This workaround uses this situation. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Deploy the script as Web Apps.

   - Set `Execute the app as:` as `Me`.
   - Set `Who has access to the app:` as `Anyone, even anonymous`. This setting is for testing.
2. Users use the deployed Web Apps like the external API.

By this, users can use your task list.

### Sample script:

The sample script is as follows. There are 2 sample scripts for Server side (your script) and Client side (user's script), respectively. You can also put both scripts in the same project.

1. Please copy and paste "Server side" to your project and deploy it as Web Apps.

   - About how to deploy Web Apps, you can see at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584324).
2. Please copy and paste "Client side" to user's project (the bound script of Spreadsheet including the button). At this time, please set the URL of Web Apps like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

#### Server side: your script

```
function doGet() {
  var tasks = getTasks();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(tasks)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function getTasks() {
  var tasklistID="mytasklistid";
  var tasks=Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistID);
  return tasks;
}
```

#### Client side: user's script

Please assign this function to the button.

```
function getTask(){
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
  var tasks = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(tasks)
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modify your script of Web Apps, please redeploy as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. This is important point for using Web Apps.**
- In this workaround, the library and client are separated. Users as the client retrieve the data from Web Apps.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: how do you call a specific function in the webApp?

Comment: @Sheils Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer. Web Apps is used as the server. When you deploy Web Apps, you retrieve the endpoint like ``https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec``. The script is run by requesting to the endpoint using ``UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)``. In my answer, the script of Web Apps is called at "Client side: user's script".

Comment: OK I created a separate script for the button and deployed it as webApp and that did the trick. So I have 3 script, bounded, standalone as library and the webApp for the button.

Comment: @Sheils Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up `getTasks()` to run automatically on a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) which will execute as you.

Edit menu (in standalone script) > Current Project's Triggers > Add Trigger button

This eliminates the need for a refresh button or web app deployment if the frequency of that time-based trigger is suffice.